# asp.net vb.net why is this IF not working?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I used to have this working as so....

```
 Dim AnnEnt As Label = FormView1.FindControl("Holiday_RemainingLabel")

    txtNoofDays.Text.ToString()
    AnnEnt.Text.ToString()

    If txtNoofDays.Text >= AnnEnt.Text Then

        lblHolRequestResponse.Text = "Your holiday could not be saved"
    Else
```

I've recently change it to this and it no longer works

```
    Dim remain As TextBox = FormView1.FindControl("Holiday_RemainingTextBox")



    txtNoofDays.Text.ToString()
    remain.Text.ToString()

    If txtNoofDays.Text >= remain.Text Then

        lblHolRequestResponse.Text = "Your holiday could not be saved"

    Else
```

What is the difference between the  textbox in the formview and label in the formview to keep this from working?

i've since tried...

```
  Dim days = txtNoofDays.Text

    days.ToString()
    AnnEnt.Text.ToString()
    remain.Text.ToString()
    If remain.Text.ToString < days.ToString Then
        lblHolRequestResponse.Text = "Your holiday could not be saved"
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. `txtNoofDays.Text.ToString()` essentially does nothing since the string is not assigned to anything. `txtNoofDays.Text >= remain.Text` will compare both strings alphabetically(according to their sort order). Are you sure that you want to do that?

Comment: they are both numbers. I just want it to compare number 2 to number 1. .. if number 1 is higher than number 2 then show message. I've tried it a few different ways but none seem to work

Comment: Not working how? Null reference error because it can't find a TextBox named "remain" ? NoOfDays looks like it might be a number to me, seeing as you are comparng strings "2" > "10"...

Comment: Comparing `"2" > "10"` will result in `true`, because "10" starts with  "1" and is the way alphabetical order works. EG: `"1", "10", "11", ..., "2", "20", "200" ...`

Comment: it seems to pick up days a number when i trace but picks up the 'remain.text.tosting' ads 'system.blah.blah.blah]

Comment: You should really CInt(AnnEnt.Text) and CInt(remain.Text) and compare them as numbers - as that's what they are. You are more likely to pick up on issues this way too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare strings numerical, cast them to numbers.

For example(asssuming they are `ints`):

```
Dim remain As TextBox = FormView1.FindControl("Holiday_RemainingTextBox")
Dim remaining = Int32.Parse(remain.Text)
Dim numOfDays = Int32.Parse(txtNoofDays.Text)

If numOfDays  >= remaining  Then
    lblHolRequestResponse.Text = "Your holiday could not be saved"
End If
```

[`Int32.Parse` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

Otherwise you're comparing alphabetically.

[`String.CompareTo` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compareto%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)